# Visual Studio Code - Notebook output cell line spacing

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

How can I control the line spacing in Visual Studio Code output cells?  See example.  The output cells have lines spaced with about 0.5 line spacing, but the terminal cells (and also code) have smaller line spacing.

[image]